# Name of xpath not working properly in Selenium and Java

Tags: java, selenium, xpath

I got this "edit" button that allows me to edit a specific row within a grid

[image]

That edit button has this:

```
<a class="action-menu-item" data-bind="attr: {target: $col.getTarget($action()), href: $action().href}, text: $action().label, click: $col.getActionHandler($action())" data-repeat-index="0" target="_self" href="https://randompageee/backend/company/index/edit/id/967/key/ee96a07876ee1fbef91d5d22dfjrrfkjaf9d40/">Edit</a>
```

It's XPATH is:

```
//*[@id="container"]/div/div[3]/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[4]/a
```

I used this in my code:

```
WebElement  elementProd = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"container\"]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[5]/div/div/button[2]"));
JavascriptExecutor executor  = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();",elementProd);
```

The thing is it sometimes work but sometimes it doesn't.

Is anything wrong with the XPATH? Should i use other instead?

---

EDIT:
[image]

It has this:

```
<td data-bind="css: getFieldClass($row()), click: getFieldHandler($row()), template: getBody()" class="data-grid-actions-cell">
<!-- ko if: $col.isSingle($row()._rowIndex) --><!-- ko repeat: {foreach: $col.getVisibleActions($row()._rowIndex), item: '$action'} --><a class="action-menu-item" data-bind="attr: {target: $col.getTarget($action()), href: $action().href}, text: $action().label, click: $col.getActionHandler($action())" data-repeat-index="0" target="_self" href="randomdfsd/backend/company/index/edit/id/967/key/ee96a07876ee1fbef91d5d22507d5882e9f03b78dasb24657d3ce9d40/">Edit</a><!-- /ko --><!-- /ko -->

<!-- ko if: $col.isMultiple($row()._rowIndex) --><!-- /ko -->
</td>
```

It's XPATH is:

```
//*[@id="container"]/div/div[3]/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[4]
```

---

On the other hand i got this:

[image]

It contains:

```
<a class="action-menu-item" data-bind="attr: {target: $col.getTarget($action()), href: $action().href}, text: $action().label, click: $col.getActionHandler($action())" data-repeat-index="0" target="_self" href="https://randomdfsd/backend/company/index/edit/id/967/key/ee9ds1d5d22507d5882e9f03b78fca79514fab24657d3ce9d40/">Edit</a>
```

It's XPATH is:

```
//*[@id="container"]/div/div[3]/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[4]/a
```

Comment: This other sister site is meant for questions like these, involving testing.  https://sqa.stackexchange.com/

Comment: The answer is likely not having a wait command.  Selenium has a bug where it sometimes won't grab the element if a wait is not implemented.  Search the other site, and you'll find it.

Comment: Hey @MacGyver thanks for commenting!. Is there any other way to name the XPATH?

Comment: XPath is typically a way of identifying an element without an id.  Used for a site YOU did not develop.  Put ids or classes on the tags of the elements you need to grab in your tests (instead of xpath) and it'll be easier to store the element.

Comment: What if you try xpath: `(//a[text()='Edit'])[1]`? You can replace `[1]` by `[2]`, `[3]` and so on depending on the row number

Comment: @MacGyver Take a look. I have edited my thread. Based on what i put, how would you define a getElementsByClass or getElementsById?. I got confused

Comment: Hey @JakyRuby why? [1] or [2] is the row or column number?

Comment: If the tag of the element has a unique id on the web page, use this instead of XPath.  driver.findElement(By.id("123")) ... instead of driver.findElement(By.xpath("x/y/z")

Comment: @new_programmer [1], [2]. [3] will be the row number in my xpath, no the column number.

Comment: @MacGyver Why the "id" is not always presented? Why i cannot find it using devs tools or whatever?

Comment: If you are not in control of development of the web page (static or dynamic content), then you are left with HTML without unique ids.  If you are testing a page that you or your company developed, then you can change the HTML or source code that rendered the HTML to place a unique id on each row, giving you an opportunity to easily grab the element of the row.

Comment: If I were developing this page, I would render a hidden column in the table, where each row would have a hidden td containing a unique id.  Like "tab1-col2-row123"

Comment: @MacGyver thanks for the explanation. I am reading this line "If you are testing a page that you or your company developed, then you can change the HTML or source code that rendered the HTML to place a unique id on each row". You mean i may tell the developer to "add" ids to each "row"?

Comment: precisely .. that will make this easier

Comment: @new_programmer yes, is a good idea to ask developers for adding ids for the elements you will use for your automation

Comment: @JakyRuby I got confused in here"a[text()". Why are you using a letter "a"? Could you please explain is there exist other alternatives thant "text()"?

Comment: a = tag of the element. text()='Edit' indicates that the text of the element must be Edit. Yes, you can filter by href for example, with this xpath: `(//a[contains(@href,"https://randompageee/backend/company/index/edit")])[1]`. The explanation for that xpath would be: An element with tag `a` which has an attribute `href` and that `href` contains the string `https://randompageee/backend/company/index/edit`

Comment: @JakyRuby what is the explanation that sometimes it will find the element by a certain name but it wont find it using a different one?

Comment: @MacGyver i got a question: May the XPATH change?Is it "safe" to use XPATH always?

Comment: yes, the xpath can change.  So it's not safe to use it for that very reason.

Answer (score 1):

The best approach for Selenium Webdriver to identify individual tr's (rows) or td (row/column combination) is to have the developer of the website (that you are testing) either place a unique id in those tags when the table is dynamically generated such as below (see reference #1).  Then obtain the row or cell of the table using that id (see reference #2) rather than using XPath.  If there are embedded tags under the tr or td, then it's safe to use XPath after that since the starting position of the HTML hierarchy of the element is fixed (see reference #3).

Reference #1:

```
<table><tr><td id="table1_row1_column1"><a>link</a></td></tr></table>
```

Reference #2:

```
WebElement elementTableTd = driver.findElement(By.id("table1_row1_column1"));
```

Reference #3:

```
WebElement elementTableA = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"table1_row1_column1\"]/a"));
```

Comment: Hey Mac, thank you for replying!. What do you mean when you say: "If there are embedded tags under the tr or td". How?

Comment: You're welcome.  "embedded" means to make an internal part of.  So in my example, I have an "a" (HTML anchor tag/element) inside the "td" (HTML table data tag/element).  So first I'm identifying the td WebDriver element using the custom id attribute of the td tag, and then adding the embedded "a" afterwards in reference 3.

Comment: meant to say "integral", not "internal".. https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/embed